# Pass options via PayPal

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating a simple checkout for a client where the visitor can check out via *PayPal*. Currently, my HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
  <fieldset> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sandbox@mcbwebdesign.co.uk" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="29" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="17.99" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Cohda Design Limited: Design Filter Tee" /> 
    <dl id="product_options"> 
      <dt><label for="option_selection1">T-shirt size:</label></dt> 
      <dd> 
        <input type="hidden" name="option_name1" value="T-shirt size" /> 
        <select name="option_selection1" id="option_selection1"> 
          <option value="Small">Small</option> 
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option> 
          <option value="Large">Large</option> 
          <option value="Extra Large">Extra Large</option> 
        </select> 
      </dd> 
      <dt><label for="option_selection2">T-shirt colour:</label></dt> 
      <dd> 
        <input type="hidden" name="option_name2" value="T-shirt colour" /> 
        <select name="option_selection2" id="option_selection2"> 
          <option value="Machine Gun Grey">Machine Gun Grey</option> 
          <option value="Blood Red">Blood Red</option> 
        </select> 
      </dd> 
    </dl> 
    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity" class="numeric" size="2" maxlength="2" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Buy now with PayPal or credit/debit card" class="button" /> 
  </fieldset> 
</form>
```

As you can see, a simply form that passes a product's details to *PayPal* for checkout. However, I'm having a problem with custom options, namely `option_name1`, `option_selection1` etc.

How can I pass custom information such as selected size and colour et al to *PayPal* for the client—and administrator—to view? As currently, testing the above with the *PayPal* sandbox feature I can't see any where anything pertaining to custom options.

Comment: Which Paypal, Express Checkout?

Answer (score 1):

option_selectX is the name of the parameter in the IPN message. What you'll want to add to the button is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">Size
<select name="os0">
<option value="Option 1">Option 1 $10.00</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2 $12.00</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3 $13.00</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Option 1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Option 2">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="12.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Option 3">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="13.00">
```

Just add 'on1' and 'os1' for colours, etc.
You can create a static button to have a look at the generated code through https://www.paypal.com/buttonfactory

Comment: If his buyer at PayPal chose the $12.00 option, would IPN see that choice at HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("option_select1") - with Nothing in the Form collection for the OTHER options? Likewise, for the option_amountX items? That is my interpretation but at breakpoints in my IPN code I am failing to see the selection made by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble passing custom variables as well, and found out that it was the naming convention that I was getting wrong (probably due to outdated docs).

I had been trying to use `option_name1` and `option_selection`, and that wasn't working. After I was this post, I tried `option_select0` and `option_amount0`.

But it wasn't until I finally found this page https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside that I realized it should really be `on0` and `os0` as the option name and option value variable names.

I hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the custom options you're referring to are simply passed back by PayPal to the callback. The premise being you then tie that particular payment to a particular order which would then have all the options you require specified.

I'm not sure if you can get PayPal to do anything with them their end.

Additionally, I don't know how much it has changed, but in my experience the PayPal sandbox can differ significantly from real PayPal, worth noting.